# Construct an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Consider vector space of functions continuous on $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ and scalar product is defined as $({\bf f}, {\bf g}) \equiv \int_{I} \rho(x) f(x)g(x) dx$. Let the generating function $G(z,x)$ be known. Let the span of $\phi_n(z) = \frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\left. G(z,x)\right|_{x=0}$ be the subspace. How to construct orthonormal basis of this subspace?

Ok, obvious way is to use the Gram-Schmidt procedure. But I would like to utilize the generating function in a manner similar to that in Krylov subspace I can use Lanczos technique.

Comment: What do you know about $G(z,x)$?

Comment: An exact expression.